# Confused on how to get out of infinite while loop with no sentinal value

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I can only use a **while Loop**. I am to prompt the user for their first and last name and the number of exams taken. Then i am to use a while loop to sum and average the exams. **Noting that each test score is a 100.**

I am getting into an infinite loop, but i don't know what value would make this loop go into false besides 0.

**Here is my Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
string fname, lname;
int tests;
int test = 100;
double test_avg;

cout << "Please enter your first and last name." << endl;
cin >> fname >> lname;

cout << "Please enter the number of exams you have taken." << endl;
cin >> tests;

while( tests > 1 )
{
    test_avg = (test * tests) / tests;
    cout << setprecision(1) << showpoint << fixed;
    cout << fname << ' ' << lname << ' ' << test_avg << "%" << endl;
    tests = 0;

}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `tests/tests` Somehow I don't think that is going to be offering up much in the way of anything helpful.

Comment: if `tests` does not change inside the loop, you'll never get out of it. this looks like an assignment and you don't seem to have put much effort.

Comment: You've never set tests to anything in your loop, it'll always be whatever the user inputs. So unless they enter 0 or less, you'll be stuck. Forever.

Comment: Aha! i didnt realize i could set tests = 0 after it averages and prompts the first and last name, and the average.

Comment: What about the test score for each exam? Or is it a constant score of 100?

Comment: You seem close, but not quite there.  If the user tells you "I'm going to enter five tests," and then enters the tests one at a time, it seems like you ought to start with the number 5 and then subract one from it each time a test is entered.  Then you'll know you're done when you reach 0.

Comment: I got it to work. The score is always 100 as i noted above. Thank you again for all of your inputs. All good tips that i will keep in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"...i am to use a while loop and average the exams"

If you do not ask a person about the score of each exam, the avg will always be 100, which I suppose is the **maximum** score.

For a loop, always ask yourself - when should the loop finish? I'd say, when a person will stop entering the results.

You can organise input as follows:

```
int scores=0;
int cnt = 0;
while (true) {
    cout << "Please enter the scores of the exams you have taken. (-1 to finish)" << endl;

    cin >> score;  // todo: check correctness - a number, 0 <= score <= 100, etc.
    if (score == -1) 
       break;
    cnt++;
    scores += score;
}

double test_avg = 0.0;
if (cnt > 0)
    test_avg = double(scores) / cnt;
```